# Is that proof correct? I'm proving that the set of injective Linear transformations in open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $T$ an inyective linear transfomation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then there exist an $\alpha>0$ such that $$||T(x)||\geq \alpha||x||$$ for all $x$. Let $S$ a linear transformation such that 
$$||T-S||<\alpha$$
So $$||T(x)||\geq \alpha||x||$$
   $$||T(x)-S(x)+S(x)||\geq \alpha||x||$$
$$||S(x)||+||T(x)-S(x)||\geq \alpha||x||$$
$$||S(x)||+||(T-S)(x)||\geq \alpha||x|| $$
$$||S(x)||+||T-S||\cdot||x||\geq \alpha||x|| \ \ (*)$$
$$||S(x)||\geq (\alpha-||T-S||)\cdot||x||$$
for all $x$. So the constant that work in this case is $\alpha-||T-S||>0$.

I have a dude in $(*)$ i can do this?? If not how can i do it in the right way? 
||T|| is the Frobenius norm of a matrix.

Comment: This is a very nice proof indeed! For (*), do you unsure about the inequality $||(T-S)x|| \leq ||T-S|| ||x||$? That can be proved by Cauchy Schwarz I guess.

Comment: Thanks you right is a Cauchy-Schwarz consequence!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicely done. For the $*$ there is no problem because $T-S$ is a bounded linear map(or bounded operator,or continuous map and many more) ,because $\|T-S\|<a$. So $\|(T-S)(x)\|\leq \|T-S\|\|x\|$